# Visualforce case assignment template visibility issue

Tags: email-template, case, merge, visualforce-template, visibility

I've created a Visualforce email template to use as notification when a case is assigned to a user (By setting the template in Support Settings > Case Assigned Template). Let's say it looks something like this:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Case {!relatedTo.CaseNumber} has been assigned to you" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Case" >
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
        <html> 
            <body>
                <p>Dear {!relatedTo.Owner.Name},</p>
            </body>
       </html>        
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

If I, as an admin user, pick a case then change the owner to another user (by checking the "Send Notification Email" option), the new owner receives the email notification from my template without problem.

However, if I log in as a standard user, and let's say the Case's owner is a queue that said user belongs to. When I try change the case ownership to someone other than the user itself, I get a "Data Not Available" error, this doesn't seem to happen when using the standard "SUPPORT: New assignment notification (SAMPLE)" template.

I believe the problem could be that the running user doesn't have access to the case record anymore and therefore cannot resolve the Visualforce merge fields because of not having visibility on the record. This theory comes to mind because if I remove the merge fields from the template, like in the following snippet, the email is sent successfully:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Case test has been assigned to you" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Case" >
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
        <html> 
            <body>
                <p>Dear test,</p>
            </body>
       </html>        
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just out of curiosity (and a bit of laziness on my part not wanting to test right now), try changing that to {!RelatedTo.Owner}.  I suspect it might be an access issue to the User object.

Comment: @drakored leaving the body empty and having just the {!relatedTo.CaseNumber} merge field in the subject also produces the error.

Comment: I see the same issue, but the record never actually leaves the current owner with less permissions.  I even tried granting direct sharing to that user's role to see if it was sharing model.  It seems like its a bug from what I can tell.

Comment: Tried one more thing.  Turned my sharing model back to public read/write/transfer, and it works fine.  It's definitely related to the sharing model, but definitely a bug since it ignored the direct sharing to that role.